# @JsonbTypeAdapter is not used by Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsonb, spring-rest, jsonb-api

I am trying to use Json-B with Spring Boot version: 2.3.1

Json-b

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

The Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping("/api/test")
    public ResponseEntity init(@Valid @RequestBody MyRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public Map<String, String> handleValidationExceptions(
            MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
            String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
            String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
            final Object rejectedValue = ((FieldError) error).getRejectedValue();
            errors.put("Rejected Value: ", rejectedValue.toString());
            errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
        });
        return errors;
    }


}
```

The request:

```
public class MyRequest  {

    @DurationMin(minutes = 1")
    @DurationMax(minutes = 10)
    @JsonbTypeAdapter(DurationAdapter.class)
    private Duration expiredTime;

    ....getter setter... 
}
```

The Json-B Adapter:

```
public class DurationAdapter implements JsonbAdapter<Duration, JsonValue> {

    @Override
    public JsonValue adaptToJson(Duration duration) throws Exception {
        final JsonNumber value = Json.createValue(duration.toMillis());
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Duration adaptFromJson(JsonValue jsonValue) throws Exception {
        final long timeInMillis = ((JsonNumber) jsonValue).longValue();
        return Duration.ofMillis(timeInMillis);
    }
}
```

I also tried this adapter as well:

```
public class DurationAdapter implements JsonbAdapter<Duration, Long> {

    @Override
    public Long adaptToJson(Duration obj) throws Exception {
        return obj.toMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public Duration adaptFromJson(Long obj) throws Exception {
        return Duration.ofMillis(obj);
    }
}
```

I used Postman to send a post request with content like this:

```
{
    "expiredTime": 6000
}
```

I put break points in my adapter but the app never ran through the break points.
I put a break points at the rejected value in the exception handler in the rest controller, and I saw that the duration was always in "seconds", not milliseconds. If the request has "expiredTime":6000, then the Java object will have expriredTime field with value Duration=6000 seconds (use debugger to see the value) and an exception will be thrown (that's why I can use the debugger at the exception handler).

*How can I make Spring boot use my Json-B Adapter?*
Thank you!

Updated: I also have specified this in application.properties:
`spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=jsonb`

Comment: Spring uses Jackson under the hood to do the mapping, not JSONB. So you'll have to find the Spring/Jackson way to get this result.

Comment: some article on Internet say that we can use Json-B with Spring by speicifying this in the application.properties ```spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=jsonb``` and I did see the difference. With it, Spring does behaves differently. When the Spring boot starts and the debug log mode is enabled, it will show many things related to Json-B like ```Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jsonb.JsonbAutoConfiguration```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, I prepared another example to show [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/jsonb-test). I excluded jackson like below just to make sure it is not used.

```
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

and used println to show in the log. and looks like this

[image]

as far as I understand `spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper` is not very effective. As long as it finds any mapper in class path spring uses that. And in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html there is no `http.converter`

Comment: I tried and it works now. So all I need to do is excluding Jackson from Spring starter web. Thank you!